# php array arithmetic loop back to start if negative

Tags: php

If i have the following array:

```
$myArray = [1 => 'a', '2' => 'b', 3 => 'c'];
```

And i have a start value of 2;

I would like to say 2 - 1 = 1 so give me value a from this array
But if 2 - 2 = 3 so give me value c.

That is, the arithmetic should be bounded in the number of elements inside my array and any values that go beyond the array indexes go back to the start or end of the array?

Comment: Read about the [modulo operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) in PHP

Comment: $myArray[count($myArray)-1]; could help. I'm confused... how would 2 - 2 == 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

write a function to search the correct key for you.

for example if your array doesn't have any left out keys:

```
<?php

function searchArray(array $array, int $key)
{
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        return $array[$key];
    }
    $key = count($array) + ($key % count($array));
    return $array[$key];
}

$myArray = [1 => 'a', '2' => 'b', 3 => 'c'];

var_dump(searchArray($myArray, 2 - 1)); // prints string(1) "a"
var_dump(searchArray($myArray, 2 - 2)); // prints string(1) "c"
var_dump(searchArray($myArray, 2 - 3)); // prints string(1) "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works BOTH ways, **forwards** and **backwards**.

```
function test($array, $key) {
   if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
     if($key>count($array)) $key=$key%count($array);
     if($key<1) $key=count($array)+$key%count($array);
     return $array[$key];
   }
}

$myArray = [1 => 'a', '2' => 'b', 3 => 'c'];

var_dump(test($myArray, -1)); // b
var_dump(test($myArray,2-2)); // c
var_dump(test($myArray,  1)); // a
var_dump(test($myArray,  6)); // c
var_dump(test($myArray, -62));// a
var_dump(test($myArray,  99));// c
```